# Reading Text file with fixed length columns using spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I need to read a text file using spring batch process and bellow is a sample file

000115989  AB0001     BC00012  030114  010100  WITHDRAWL FROM SAVING             100.00

It doesn't have any column header and each column has a fixed length and delimited by two blank spaces.

Here I can't use DelimitedLineTokenizer for two blank spaces as columns can also have leading or trailing blank spaces .

Is there any work around so that I read each column with its specific length after that I can trim that.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `FixedLengthTokenizer` (http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/FixedLengthTokenizer.html).  This allows you to set how lines are parsed by column instead of by delimiter.

Comment: Hey thanks Michael,currently I have Implemented that but in my case the file is very large (almost 500 columns) so mapping with the fixed column length would be difficult and any change in file format will result a lot of rework on mapping.

Comment: @Michael - Could you please guide here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63674370/caused-by-org-springframework-batch-item-file-transform-incorrectlinelengthexce ?